# View to global class variable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

why the "view" in this lane is always red..

```
final TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
```

I always get this error like below:

```
"error: cannot find symbol variable view"
```

Sample code which I tried:

ProfileFragment class:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    ImageView profilsettings = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar_image);
    profilsettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog();
            bottomSheetDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialog.getTag());


        }

    });
    return view;
}

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("my_broadcast")){
            final TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
            username.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));


        }

    }


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("my_broadcast"));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me what do I have to change?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't have any `view` variable visible in the scope of that statement. The only `view` variable is in totally different class.

Comment: And how can I make the view variable visible? I am beginner:p I don't know how.
(ProfileFragment and BroadcastReceiver is the same class. Someone just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because the variable view is not accessible to your `BroadcastReceiver`. So the compiler is saying *error: cannot find symbol variable view*

To make view accessible to BroadcastReceiver you can follow @Amine answer or you can easily make `view` as`member` variable.

Make view object as a member variable like below

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
private View view;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    ImageView profilsettings = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar_image);
    profilsettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog();
            bottomSheetDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialog.getTag());


        }

    });
    return view;
}

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("my_broadcast")){
            final TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
            username.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));


        }

    }


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("my_broadcast"));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
   }
}
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `TextView` using the available `context` like this

```
final TextView username = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
```